# Function argument as generic type

Tags: swift

I'm making the following generic memoization function is there anyway to make the `Fn` type generic

```
func memoize<Arg: Hashable, Ret, Fn: ((Arg) -> Ret)>(_ fn: @escaping Fn) -> Fn {
    var cache: [Arg:Ret] = [:]
    return {
        (x: Arg) -> Ret in
        let ret = cache[x, default: fn(x)]
        cache[x] = ret
        return ret
        
    }
}
```

I could do this but it's hard to read.

```
func memoize<Arg: Hashable, Ret>(_ fn: @escaping ((Arg) -> Ret)) -> ((Arg) -> Ret) {
```

Comment: Do you mean a `typealias`?

Comment: err I guess just learning swift

Answer (score 1):

There are no function-level typealiases in Swift.  A global typealias will make it look worse, because then you'll lose the arrow.

C# calls this one a ["`Func`"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0).

```swift
typealias Func<Arg, Ret> = (Arg) -> Ret

func memoize<Arg: Hashable, Ret>(
  _ fn: @escaping Func<Arg, Ret>
) -> Func<Arg, Ret> {
```

So just write it in multiple lines and lose those extra sets of parentheses. (You also don't need to explicitly type the closure.)

```swift
func memoize<Arg: Hashable, Ret>(
  _ fn: @escaping (Arg) -> Ret
) -> (Arg) -> Ret {
  var cache: [Arg: Ret] = [:]
  return { x in
    let ret = cache[x, default: fn(x)]
```

---

You also may find something like this useful.

```swift
return { cache[$0, valueAddedIfNil: fn($0)] }
```

```swift
public extension Dictionary {
  subscript(
    key: Key,
    valueAddedIfNil getValue: @autoclosure() -> Value
  ) -> Value {
    mutating get {
      self[key]
      ?? {
        self[key] = getValue()
        return self[key]!
      } ()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! interesting syntax - not familiar with @autoclosure